# Amazon S3, streaming video while still uploading it

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I wanted to know if it would be possible to stream video while you are uploading it.

For example I have a 100MB video uploading to s3, the first 50MB are uploaded, so can a client start reproducing the video through cloudfront even tho it's not yet fully uploaded?

Or does S3 first wait for the upload to completely finish, then assemble the video file, and then publish it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

S3 provides **read-after-write** consistency for PUTS of new objects. The data will not be able to read until the write is complete.

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.

[S3 consistency model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel)